# Set Canvas.Top for UserControl

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties, geometry

I'm creating simple circle control (with center and radius properties) based on ellipse.

Code for using my control is simple (control is in Canvas):

```
<my:Circle Canvas.Left="1300" Canvas.Top="1243" CenterX="800" CenterY="800" Radius="100" />
```

I've created 3 DP's: CenterX, CenterY and Radius.

How can I change Canvas.Top and Canvas.Bottom from callbacks?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Call `Canvas.SetLeft(someControl, someDouble)`.